# What StackExchange board is best for asking about setting up a linux server for VPN, Jira, GitLab and some VMs?

Tags: support

I am very far from being an expert in systems admin (I'm a programmer) but I want to set up my own private work environment with a VPN, Jira, GitLab and a bunch of VMs (some with linux servers, some with Windows) and I have no idea where to start asking the questions.

Do I use SuperUser? ServerFault? Is there a better forum elsewhere?

Comment: Start with the documentation and work out from there.

Comment: @Iain But the reason I'm not sure where to ask is that I need to ask the more general, "What is the best way to achieve this?" I have only 1 server, so it all needs to live on there, but I don't know if I should install a base linux server and do all the services as separate VMs (or containers, etc) or some other setup.

Comment: There is no "best" way. You won't get it right the first time, or even the second time, and quite possibly not the third time. It being a learning environment, start creating VMs and jump in.

Answer (score 2):

ServerFault is probably not the right place to ask your questions.

*Specific* questions about installing and configuring software would be on topic here, but not the general overview you seem to want.  "What is the best way to achieve this?" is both too broad and too much a matter of opinion to get good answers here.

Wanting to put all of those tools on one server because it's your personal environment would also likely get your questions closed because that's not a typical sysadmin environment.